# Code block in spoiler with markdown

Tags: gitlab, markdown

Is there any way in markdown to combine the code (inside ```) with the spoiler (after !>) syntax in order to obtain some code inside a spoiler ?

I'm using the markdown implemented in GitLab.

Comment: The answer will depend on the specific Markdown library you are using. For example, the [original implementation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't support fenced code blocks (it uses indentation for code blocks) or spoiler tags at all. Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure what library I'm using, I'm writing a documentation in the wiki section proposed in Gitlab.

Comment: That suggests that you're using [GitLab Flavored Markdown](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/markdown/markdown.md). I've never seen the spoiler tag before, and it doesn't seem to be listed in the documentation…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Chris mentions in a comment, [GitLab Flavored Markdown](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/markdown/markdown.md) doesn't appear to mention anything about supporting "spoiler" syntax (after `!>`). Additionally, "spoiler" syntax is not an "official" syntax (neither are fenced code blocks as @Chris points out) and is not very common. Personally, I'm not aware of any particular Markdown implementation which supports it. That said, as I understand the syntax, it is basically an extension of the blockquote syntax. So, whatever works for blockquotes should work for spoilers if the implementation you are using supports spoilers.

Another issue to be aware of is that not all Markdown implementations support Fenced Code Blocks, and not all that do support them equally. For example, some of the earliest implementations do not support the fenced code blocks being nested. Therefore, depending on which Markdown implementation you are using, you may get different results (I have no idea which implementation GitLab uses). That is the price you pay for using non-standard features.

In any event, assuming the implementation you are using has full support, the following would presumably work:

````
!> ```javascript
!> alert("42");
!> ```
````

Note that I authored my code block as normal. Then I simply inserted the three characters at the beginning of each line (exclamation point, greater than symbol, and a space). If that doesn't work, then a safe assumption is that the implementation does not support one or more of the non-standard features required.

Comment: Yea, unfortunatly, GitLab Flavored Markdown  doesn't support the spoiler syntax.

Answer (score 43):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#details-and-summary

You can use raw HTML

```markdown
<p>
<details>
<summary>Click this to collapse/fold.</summary>

These details <em>remain</em> <strong>hidden</strong> until expanded.

<pre><code>PASTE LOGS HERE</code></pre>

</details>
</p>
```

or now GitLab supports Markdown within `<details>` blocks

````markdown
<details>
<summary>Click this to collapse/fold.</summary>

These details _remain_ **hidden** until expanded.

```
PASTE LOGS HERE
```

</details>
````

Comment: Note that markdown is now fully supported inside <details> blocks on the latest version of Gitlab

Comment: Not sure how it is supported now, but i had to add emptyline after opening <details> tag to make markdown work. Just fyi, it can be tricky.

Comment: I'd add that you can use the `lang` attribute on your `code` tag to trigger syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 13):

The following should do the trick:

```
<details>
  <summary>Click to expand</summary>
  Whatever
</details>
```

Answer (score 5):

For syntax highlighting inside a code block wrapped in a spoiler these two approaches work in GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.3.4-ee:

### HTML-only

With `lang` inside the `code` tag (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181339/code-block-in-spoiler-with-markdown#comment101709097_50623322) by @Denis Chevalier)

```html
<details>
<summary>Initial draft</summary>

<pre><code lang="python">
YOUR CODE
</code></pre>
</details>
```

### Markdown code-fencing

Mind the whitespace before the code fence (triple backticks) (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181339/code-block-in-spoiler-with-markdown#comment99318000_50623322) by @validname)

````markdown
<details>
<summary>Initial draft</summary>

```python
YOUR CODE
\```  <- remove backslash: StackOverflow markdown parsing is broken 
</details>
````

Comment: Thanks, works in CE too, that blank line was actually crucial ^^